# Azure AD B2C and aka.ms/mfasetup

Tags: entra-id, azure-mfa

I have an Azure AD tenant and I created an Azure AD B2C tenant for an app that I am building.

The "short link" for MFA setup is https://aka.ms/mfasetup but that allows me to configure MFA for my primary tenant?

Is there a URL for the MFA portal that contains the tenantid?

or How can you switch tenant in the MFA Portal?

Answer (score 2):

B2C works a bit different from a normal tenant, where the MFA info is registered using Default Flows or Custom Policies.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow

https://aka.ms/mfasetup seems to only work for a normal tenant registration.

Comment: thanks i'm still stuck on this. im basically locked out of my azure AD b2c tenant.   i'll give this a shot

Comment: If you're locked out and have no other means of changing your MFA registration, then a support case with MS support is in order I'm afraid